# Parse Json data with space in Python

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I trying to load JSON file but its not working with space.

If i try to load  `!ping Steve` its working and `!ping "George Stephen"` its working but if i try to load `!ping George Stephen` its not working.

json file sample

```
{"people": [
{"Name": "Steve", "Sex": "Male", "age": "30"},
{"Name": "Rachel", "Sex": "Female", "age": "25"},
{"Name": "George Stephen", "Sex": "Male", "age": "22"} ] }
```

---

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def ping(ctx, namesList):
  with open('data.json') as json_file:
    d = json.load(json_file)
    for p in d['people']:
      if(p['Name'] in (namesList)):
        await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, p)
```

Comment: I'm no Python programmer but did you try `!ping "George Stephen"` or `!ping George\ Stephen`. The JSON is pretty fine, the issue is with the Discord itself I guess.

Comment: i tried `!ping "George Stephen"`  it works but without " " it not works.

Comment: This is Discord issue then.

Comment: So how to make it work. or can't it read space as other characters?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51214976/6779307

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thank you it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discord.py missing required argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214915/discord-py-missing-required-argument)