# Discord.py method doesn't get argument

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am making a .py bot.

When I write '.hello hello' to my bot in Discord, the method hello doesn't get an arg hello,
as explained in docs here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html

and I get the error:

```
Ignoring exception in command hello:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 856, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 790, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: arg is a required argument that is missing.
```

Here is the code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
# . - это запуск команды

@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print('BOT connected')

@client.command( pass_context = True) # use for chat prefix.

async def hello(ctx, arg):
    author = ctx.message.author
    
    await ctx.send(f'{author.mention}' + arg)

# Connect 
token = open( 'token.txt','r').readline()
client.run( token )
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214915/discord-py-missing-required-argument

Comment: no, this link is on totally different subject.  And besides, the core is that discord.py library was recently changed,and my videocourse that I follow, is somehow outdated.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says "MissingRequiredArguments" I assume you are trying to do something like .hello (your sentence) and bot mentions and adds your sentence in front of it? Then this here should work. The `*` consumes everything you say after the command. For example: if you added "hello this is a test" but didn't add the `*` before your arg/query, it will only take the first word,  which is "hello" in this case.
Also use `ctx.author` instead of ctx.message.author and you can do further stuff like `ctx.author.name` or `ctx.author.mention` etc etc.

```
@client.command() 
async def hello(ctx, *, query):
    author = ctx.author
    await ctx.send(f"{author.mention} {query}")
```

Comment: yes, that's really what I want to get my sentence in front of bot's one.
In fact, i cant' check this syntax with * - after I applyed, thiis function doesn't work in my bot.
Thanks, I try now and later.

Comment: Let me know if that fails, if that does happen, contact me on discord UnidentifiedComponent#8118